# Filter messages before deserialization based on headers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Sometimes messages can be filtered out before the deserialization based on header values . Are there any existing patterns for this scenario using spring kafka. I am thinking implementing similar to ErrorHandlingDeserializer in addition to delegate take filter predicate also as property. Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same technique used by the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` to return a "marker" object instead of doing the deserialization, then add a `RecordFilterStrategy`, that filters records with such objects, to the listener (container factory when using `@KafkaListener` or use a filtering adapter for an explicit listener).

**EDIT**

Spring Boot and adding a filter...

```java
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setRecordFilterStrategy(myFilter());
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: are there any plans to add record filter strategy and container error handler as properties.

Comment: Your question is not tagged with [tag:spring-boot]; if you mean exposed as boot properties used by boot auto-configuration then, if a single `ErrorHandler` bean is in the context, it is wired into the container factory. There is currently no auto-config for the filter strategy,  you could try opening a new feature against boot, but it's easy enough to override Boot's auto-configured factory `@Bean` to set additional properties. If you don't mean Spring Boot, then I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to easily add a filter.

Comment: thanks Gary. yes i meant the spring boot auto configured bean. We are planning the same as you suggested. (just trying to manage with properties and auto configured bean since we have many services with different properties profiles). will tag with spring-boot

Comment: I am sure they'll consider a pull request; it shouldn't be much different to how the error handler is injected. That said, it probably doesn't make sense for an application that has several listeners since each listener would probably want a different filter, so a custom container factory would be needed for each. Perhaps a better solution would be to request us (spring-kafka) to add a filter strategy to the `@KafkaListener` annotation directly; again, a PR would be appreciated :)

Comment: But actually in this solution the payload is deserialized and then the recordStrategy is applied... Is there a way to not deserialize the payload if headers values are rejected ?

Comment: You would have to add logic to the deserializer - e.g. examine the headers before deserializing and set the value() to some marker object that allows the filter to skip it.

Comment: A bit pity to have this logic in the deserializer :( But I got the point, thank you :)