# Spring Integration and Kafka: How to filter messages based on message header

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I have a question which builds on this question: [Filter messages before deserialization based on headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843328/filter-messages-before-deserialization-based-on-headers)

I'd like to filter by kafka consumer record header using Spring Integration DSL.

Currently I have this flow:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow readTicketsFlow(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper,
                                EventService<Ticket> service) {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties);

    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    consumerFactory, TICKET_TOPIC))
            .transform(fromJson(Ticket.class, new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(jacksonObjectMapper)))
            .handle(service)
            .get();
}
```

How can I register `org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordFilterStrategy` in this flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a `.filter()` element to the flow.

```
.filter("!'bar'.equals(headers['foo'])")
```

Will filter out (ignore) any messages with a header named `foo` equal to `bar`.

Note Spring Kafka's `RecordFilterStrategy` has the reverse sense of Spring Integration filters

```java
public interface RecordFilterStrategy<K, V> {

    /**
     * Return true if the record should be discarded.
     * @param consumerRecord the record.
     * @return true to discard.
     */
    boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<K, V> consumerRecord);

}
```

Spring Integration filters discard messages if the filter returns false.

**EDIT**

Or you can add a `RecordFilterStrategy` to the channel adapter.

```java
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory(), TEST_TOPIC1)
                .recordFilterStrategy(record -> {
                    Header header = record.headers().lastHeader("foo");
                    return header != null ? new String(header.value()).equals("bar") : false;
                })
                ...
```

Comment: I wonder what is wrong with a `recordFilterStrategy(RecordFilterStrategy<K, V> recordFilterStrategy)` option of the `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`?..

Comment: Oops; yes; forgot about that :(